# An alternative word choice for "oh shit/oops"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there a verb for "oh shit"?
As in someone was shocked, but instead of shocked the verb means "oh shit". 
The context is basically that this person lied about something and instantly she regretted, so she was "oh shit (verb version)". 
I want to put it in a way so it says she was _____. The word could mean she regretted for saying that, but at the same time she feels awkward.

Comment: 'Contrite' might be the word you are looking for.  It's meaning per OLD is 'very sorry for something bad tht you have done'.  Example: She was contrite the morning after her angry outburst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not a verb, and not currently in popular use, I think the word *nonplussed* fits your needs ([from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonplussed)):

> unsure about what to say, think, or do : perplexed

In something similar to your given context, here is how it could be used:

> Sue had lied about completing the report, and when her co-worker confronted her, was so *nonplussed* she was unable to respond.